# move the canvas image like Pendulum

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d-games

i`m building html5 games like city blocs i want to move rob picture like Pendulum

the drwing function

```
function draw(){
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(20,0);
ctx.translate(box1.width/2,0);
ctx.rotate(val*(Math.PI/180));
ctx.drawImage(box1,box1.X,box1.Y);
ctx.restore();


}
```

now i have rotation method ready 
i tried this to move it as i said

```
function boxPendolAnim(){

loop1 = setInterval(function(){
val =  val -0.1;

},200);

setInterval(function(){
if (val <=-2) {
clearInterval(loop1);
setInterval(function(){
val = val +0.1;
},200);

}; 

},200);

}
```

but it work only once no more then stopped 
i want function to move the picture like pendulum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

- Just use 1 setInterval.
- In the function executed by setInterval, increase the angle until it is at your desired maximum and then decrease the angle.

This is an example of an image in pendulum motion:

[image]

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/n9KrM/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


        var rotation=0;             // start at horizontal
        var direction=Math.PI/60;   // 3 degrees change each loop


        var box1=new Image();
        box1.onload=function(){
            setInterval(go,40);
        }
        box1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";


        function go(){

            // set the new rotation
            rotation+=direction;
            if(rotation>Math.PI || rotation<0){
                direction=-direction;
                rotation+=direction;
            }

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            draw();

        }


        function draw(){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(120,40);
            ctx.rotate(rotation);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0,0);
            ctx.lineTo(40,0);
            ctx.rect(40,-15,30,30);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.drawImage(box1,0,0,box1.width,box1.height,40,-15,30,30);
            ctx.restore();
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should i do if i want the speed reach to 0 in the top points and max speed in horizontal point ?

Comment: The pendulum is at the bottom when the angle is PI/2. So when the angle approaches PI/2 from either side you would speed up the change in rotation.  One way is to add an easing variable like this: rotation+=direction*easing.  The easing variable would be slowest at angle 0 & PI (maybe easing=1.00).  The easing variable  would be fastest at angle PI/2 (maybe easing=3.00). For example, you could calc easing like this: 1+2.00*Math.abs((PI/2)-direction)/(PI/2)

Comment: OOPS! I had a "math moment" in my comment above.  For example, you could calc easing like this: 5-4.00*Math.abs((Math.PI/2)-rotation)/(Math.PI/2);